# Making Default attributes warning popup go away?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, default

I've got multiple county feature classes within a feature dataset. Within one of the county features I created a new field with coded subtypes. Whenever I'm editing this county in Arc and change this new fields attributes to one of these subtypes I get this pop-up:

> You are changing the subtype for this feature. Do you want to change
>   the default attributes for the feature to those defined by the new
>   subtype?

Any ideas why this happens and how to make it stop?

Answer (score 3):

## From ArcGIS Desktop

From `C:\Program Files(x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\Utilities`
*(depends on your version and installing path)*

Open `AdvancedArcMapSettings` as administrator

From the `Editor` tab, uncheck `Warn on subtype change`

[image]

Then restart your ArcMap...

## From ArcGIS Pro

Click on `Project` to go to the backstage area.

Choose `Options` and select the `Editing` item under `Application`.

Uncheck the `Warn on subtype change`

[image]